# View Attach/Detach History for SQL Database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that for the second time (last time was many months ago) just disappeared.  Physical files are there, but the database isn't showing up in SQL server, and I have to re-attach it.  I'm thinking something is detaching it, but I have no idea how to find out what.

Is there an attach/detach history anywhere?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic996650-1550-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I came across that one in Google, but it seems to only address fining the file list to restore the MDF.  I know which MDF it is and restored it, I'm just trying to find out who/when detached it.

Comment: don't think that level of history can be get